# Concatenating files created with filecontents

Tags: verbatim, filecontents

I am creating a large number of data files "on the fly" using the filecontents package.

I need to be able to concatenate these files in various permutations
For example in the MWE below, I would need to be able to create a new file consisting of 
data2+data1 and so on for various purposes. Is there any way to do this? I suppose the question might be similar to asking whether I can expand a macro/file input within a verbatim?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.tex}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.tex}
Line 3
Line 4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data3.tex}
Line 5
Line 6
\end{filecontents*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could read them into tex and write them out but simpler if you allow `--shell-escape` would be `\immediate\write18{cat data2.tex data1.tex > foo.tex}`

Comment: That looks promising. However when I add line you suggest to mwe I do get a foo.tex but that is empty (even after a second pass). I am calling latex as ..\win32\latexmk.exe" -f -xelatex --shell-escape mwe.tex, and all other shell functions work fine for me. (How would I do your first method?)

Comment: What does work is \immediate\write18{%
    echo "" >  foobar.txt;
    echo "" >> foobar.txt;
    echo "--------" >> foobar.txt;
    echo "Foo: foo" >> foobar.txt;
    echo "Foo: foo" >> foobar.txt;
    echo "Bar: bar" >> foobar.txt
    }   -- but that is very complicated versus your idea

Comment: Probably because in windows there is no cat.... so what is non shell method as I don't much like mine

Comment: Actually I'm on windows but use the cygwin bash shell so have cat and things,. this answer has some windows alternatives that shoudl work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477271/concatenate-text-files-with-windows-command-line-dropping-leading-lines

Comment: OK good. Grabbed cat from here http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUtils.zip and it works a dream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read them into tex and write them out but simpler if you allow `--shell-escape` would be

```
\immediate\write18{cat data2.tex data1.tex > foo.tex}
```

(`cat` is available for windows, as noted in comments).